# MISRA2012 Rule 12.1 Extra parentheses recommended

Tags: c, misra

I'm trying to fix the compliance of my code to misra C. During the static analysis, I had this violation:

> Rule 12.1: Extra parentheses recommended. A conditional operation is
> the operand of another conditional operator.

The code is:

```
if (CHANNEL_STATE_GET(hPer, channel) != CHANNEL_STATE_READY)
{
    retCode = ERROR;
}
```

where CHANNEL_STATE_GET is a macro as follow:

```
#define CHANNEL_STATE_GET(__HANDLE__, __CHANNEL__)\
  (((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_1) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[0] :\
   ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_2) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[1] :\
   ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_3) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[2] :\
   ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_4) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[3] :\
   ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_5) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[4] :\
   (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[5])
```

Do you have any idea to solve this violation?

BR,
Vincenzo

Comment: Have you considered using extra parentheses?

Comment: Are `CHANNEL_1`, `CHANNEL_2` and so on adjacent integers? Then you can make this code branch free and more MISRA compliant all at once, by using table look-up instead.

Comment: If at all possible, *please* replace `CHANNEL_STATE_GET` with an array lookup, as other comments and answers are suggesting!  Fetching things based on a numeric index — like a channel number — is what arrays are *for*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note (as more or less implied by Lundins comment....), I answer more about how to approach MISRA findings (and those of a few other analysis tools I suffered from ....).

I would first try to get a better angle on what the finding is actually describing. And with a nested structure like shown, that takes some re-looking. So ...

I would apply indentation, just to make life easier while editing and then, well, add some more `()` in inviting places, e.g. in this case so as to enclose each `x?y:z` into one pair.

```
#define CHANNEL_STATE_GET(__HANDLE__, __CHANNEL__)\
  (        ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_1) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[0] :\
    (      ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_2) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[1] :\
      (    ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_3) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[2] :\
        (  ((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_4) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[3] :\
          (((__CHANNEL__) == CHANNEL_5) ? (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[4] :\
                                          (__HANDLE__)->ChannelState[5]  \
          )                                                              \
        )                                                                \
      )                                                                  \
    )                                                                    \
  )
```

This is to address what the quoted finding is about.
I would not feel bad about sprinkling a few more around e.g. each `CHANNEL_N`.

(I admit that I did not test my code against a MISRA checker. I try to provide an approach. I hope this fixes the mentioned finding, possibly replacing it with another one.... MISRA in my experience is good at that.... I do not even expect this to solve all findings.)

Comment: There's a whole lot of other MISRA violations here as well. It's not as easy as just throwing more parenthesis on the problem.

Comment: @Lundin You are right, but to really clean all of them up probably more context is needed. And the answer is part general (i.e. "add more ()") and part advice ("how to approach"), part focused on the one finding quoted and not really at all about solving all MISRA. I will write that into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: ... and a MISRA checker would be needed, which I currently have misplaced somehow, though otherwise I of course diligently apply MISRA checking to all my private projects. Cough.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch ! this fixed the violation, previously I tried to put extra parentheses in the if statement without success. 
Thank you again

Comment: @VincenzoCristiano If this was the only MISRA violation you got from your checker, then I would suggest that it's a quite broken one.

Answer (score 2):

There's several concerns here, as far as MISRA C is concerned:

- There's various rules saying that macros and complex expressions should be surrounded by parenthesis, and that code shouldn't rely on the C programmer knowing every single operator precedence rule. You can solve that by throwing more parenthesis on the expression, but that's just the top of the iceberg.
- The `?:` operator is considered a "composite operator" and so expressions containing it are considered "composite expressions" and come with a bunch of extra rules 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8. Meaning that there is a lot of rules regarding when and how this macro may be mixed with other expressions - the main concerns are implicit, accidental type conversions.
- The use of function-like macros should be avoided in the first place.
- Identifiers beginning with multiple underscores aren't allowed by the C language since it reserves those for the implementation (C17 7.1.3).

The easier and recommended fix is just to forget about that macro, since it will just cause massive MISRA compliance headache. Also at a glance, it looks like very inefficient code with nested branches. My suggested fix:

- In case `hPer` happens to be a pointer to pointer (seems like it), then dereference it and store the result in a plain, temporary pointer variable. Don't drag the nasty pointer to pointer syntax around across the whole function/macro.
- Replace this whole macro with a (inline) function or a plain array table look-up, depending on how well you've sanitized the `channel` index.
- Ensure that `CHANNEL_1` to `CHANNEL_5` are adjacent integers from 0 to 4. If they aren't, use some other constant or look-up in between.

A MISRA compliant re-design might look like this:

```
typedef enum
{
  CHANNEL_1,
  CHANNEL_2,
  CHANNEL_3,
  CHANNEL_4,
  CHANNEL_5
} channel_t;

// state_t is assumed to be an enum too

state_t CHANNEL_STATE_GET (const HANDLE* handle, channel_t channel)
{
  if((uint32_t)channel > (uint32_t)CHANNEL_5)
  {
    /* error handling here */
  }

  uint32_t index = (uint32_t)channel;
  return handle[index];
}

...

if (CHANNEL_STATE_GET(*hPer, channel) != CHANNEL_STATE_READY)
```

If you can trust the value of `channel` then you don't even need the function, just do a table look-up. Also note that MISRA C encourages "handle" in this case to be an opaque type, but that's a chapter of its own.

Note that this code is also assuming that `HANDLE` isn't a pointer hidden behind a typedef as in Windows API etc - if so then that needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: identifiers beginning with underscores aren't allowed sure, but these are macro arguments, aren't they fine? the checker (helix qac) doesnì't show me anything about this.   Same thing for the other violations that you shown in the answer.

Comment: @VincenzoCristiano The underscore part isn't actually a MISRA rule but a standard C rule. It doesn't matter that they are macros, they use up names in the so-called "ordinary namespace". There is no reason why you should be using underscores anyway. Certain older coding standards use them for private data but that was always a bad idea (been there done that).

Comment: @VincenzoCristiano As for the other remarks, it depends on how the macro is used in the calling code. You don't want one which works in some situations but causes MISRA violations in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Other comments and answers are suggesting replacing the cumbersome `CHANNEL_STATE_GET` macro with a much simpler array lookup, and I strongly agree with that recommendation.

It's possible, though, that the definitions of `CHANNEL_1` through `CHANNEL_5` are not under your control, such that you can't guarantee that they're consecutive small integers as would be required.  In that case, I recommend writing a small function whose sole job is to map a `channel_t` to an array index.  The most obvious way to do this is with a `switch` statement:

```
unsigned int map_channel_index(channel_t channel)
{
    switch(channel) {
        case CHANNEL_1: return 0;
        case CHANNEL_2: return 1;
        case CHANNEL_3: return 2;
        case CHANNEL_4: return 3;
        case CHANNEL_5: return 4;
        default:        return 5;
    }
}
```

Then you can define the much simpler

```
#define CHANNEL_STATE_GET(handle, channel) \
        ((handle)->ChannelState[map_channel_index(channel)])
```

Or, you can get rid of `CHANNEL_STATE_GET` entirely by replacing

```
if(CHANNEL_STATE_GET(hPer, channel) != CHANNEL_STATE_READY)
```

with

```
if((*hPer)->ChannelState[map_channel_index(channel)] != CHANNEL_STATE_READY)
```

Comment: I'm in Albania right now... but I usually work from Paris France, 6 hours east of Cambridge. I used to work there at 1033 Mass Ave, before the FSF moved in :)

Comment: Looking at your profile, I undeleted the fun question, and it took 7 mns for a mod to strike back. So I guess C unions are a touchy subject and fun in general is outlawed.

Comment: If you come to Paris, make sure to give me a buzz so we can meet and have a good dinner. I'll tell you if I swing by Boston anytime.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to fix some seriously odd code like this, it's often a good idea to take one or two big steps backwards.

We know that `hPer` refers to an array.  We have some troublesome code that is indexing into that array and pulling out one of the channel states.  But this code is, frankly, pretty awful.  Even if the MISRA checker weren't complaining about it, any time you've got five nested `?:` operators, performing a cumbersome by-hand emulation of what ought to be a simple array lookup, it's a sure sign that something isn't right, and that there's probably a better way to do it.  So what might that better way be?

One way to approach that question is to ask, *How is the `ChannelState` array filled in?  And is there any other code that also fetches out of it?*

You've only asked us about this one line that your MISRA checker is complaining about.  That suggests that the code that fills in the `ChannelState` array, and any other code that fetches out of it, is not drawing complaints.  Perhaps that other code accesses the `ChannelState` array in some different, hopefully better way. Perhaps the underlying problem is that the programmer who wrote this `CHANNEL_STATE_GET` macro was unaware of that other code, had not been properly educated on this program's coding conventions and available utility routines.  Perhaps it's perfectly acceptable to directly index a `ChannelState` array using a `channel` value.  Or perhaps there's already something like the `map_channel_index` function which I suggested in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937082#72938432).

So, do yourself a favor: spend a few minutes seeking out some other code that accesses the `ChannelState` array.  You might learn something very interesting.